# How can use Configuration file for instead of coding in .net remoting?

Tags: .net, config, .net-remoting

I have a server that I want to create instance from it and call a method like this:

```
IClass cus = (IClass)(Activator.GetObject(typeof(IClass), 
"tcp://localhost:8888/IClass"));
cus.SomeMethod();
```

it works well but I want to use configuration file like this:

```
  <client url="tcp://localhost:8888/IClass">
        <activated
          type="MyServer.Server, MyServer"/>
     </client>
```

to have an instance of it. How can I handle this.
Thank you

Comment: Do you really have to use legacy .NET Remoting in 2018?